# testWeb(jspackage.JSAssignmentDiscount): Table tag should have 3 rows and check with the requirements for CSS for table and tr false

Tags: css, html

**Specification:**

Product name and product price and season should be within a table. Product name and product price are both text boxes, with the tag name `name` and `price` respectively. Season is a dropdown box with the tag name `season`. The dropdown box will have the following values:

· summer - SUMMER SALE

· newyear  - NEW YEAR SALE

· clearance - CLEARANCE SALE

Product name should not be empty, and should contain only alphabetical characters or spaces. The `price` textbox cannot be empty, and should be a number with a value greater than zero.

The table should be `margin-left` aligned with `35%`, and an outer `border-style` of `solid 5px` and `30%` `width`. The space between the element and the border must be `10px`.

```css
table {
  border-style: solid;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-left: 35%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product Price</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price" required min="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Season</td>
    <td>
      <select id="season" name="season">
        <option value="summer">SUMMER SALE</option>
        <option value="newyear">NEW YEAR SALE</option>
        <option value="clearance">CLEARANCE SALE</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---------------------------------------------------------------**Error**-------------------------------------------------------------

```
testWeb(jspackage.JSAssignmentDiscount):
Table tag should have 3 rows and check with the requirements for CSS for table and tr
false
```

Comment: Your code meets all of the requirements you specify. Check that your lecturer's script is validating your assignment correctly.

Comment: No thank you; I'm under no obligation to help you. If I knew the answer to your question, I would have written an answer. Wait until someone comes along who knows the answer, or take it up with your lecturer. `testWeb()` is not shown in your question, and could have a problem in it itself.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to you `css` and this error will be resolved.

```
tr,td{
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;

                border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;
                border-width: 2px;
            }
```

Comment: Error: Fail 1 - Table tag should have 3 rows and check with the requirements for CSS for table and tr